# HTML File input JS events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

Are there any JavaScript events in `type=file` input? I.E. I would like to add an extra `file input` upon selecting file in one of allready created:

Diagram:] :

```
file input 1
file input 2
file input 3
```

user selects some file in `input 1` and JS adds new file input

```
file input 1 - somefile.txt
file input 2
file input 3
*NEW* file input 4
```

I'm looking for meaningful event, on which i can bind `addFileInput` method.

I also use jQuery 1.4 :]

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as an `input[type=html]` ;)

Comment: I believe `onchange` should work.

Comment: You might consider supporting `<input type="file" multiple=""/>` in browsers that support it. More: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/multiple-file-input-in-firefox-3-6/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe `onchange` should work.

Comment: @TylerCollier The vanilla event is `element.onChange = function() {};` and the jQuery equivalent is `$(element).delegate('change', function() {});`.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the event logged by Firebug when selecting a file with Firebug:

- click clientX=885, clientY=207
- blur
- focus
- change
- DOMActivate
- DOMActivate
- mouseout clientX=162, clientY=27

I guess change, is the one you are looking for:

```
$ ('#your_form_id input[type=file]').live ('change', function () {
  $(this).parent ().append ($('<input type="file" />'));
})
```

you just have to adapt the selector and the previous code should work

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `type=file` ?

The only meaningful way is use both onclick and onchanged and keep track of the contents to see if it is changed.