# what listeners are called when a file is selected from a file chooser in javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, event-listener

I'm working on creating an upload button for my website but I'm unable to trigger events based on when the file is selected for the upload. I was under the impression that the .submit function did this but I'm unable to get any results from this.
HTML

```
    <input type="button" id="uploadbutton" value="Upload File" />
    <form action="includes/uploader.php" method="POST" id="fileupload_form">
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple style="display:none;">
        <input id="server" type="hidden" name="server" value="upload">
        <input type="hidden" id="storeA" value="statement_upload" name="storeA">
    </form>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
var fileupload = $("#fileupload");

$("#uploadbutton").click( function(){
    fileupload.click();
});

$("#fileupload_form").submit( function(e){}
```

This javascript function will not run when trying to select the file and no errors are given. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML File input JS events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296572/html-file-input-js-events)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Listen on `fileupload.on('change', function(){})` to get what and when was chosen in file selector.

Comment: is it "changed" or "change" ?

Comment: I tried that but it still isn't going into the function. I have an alert as soon as it gets inside and its not making it that far.

Comment: is there a solution for when you select the same file two times in a row? because "change" wont be triggered  the second time then, since nothing changed.

Comment: @InsOp that was what also brought me here. I found the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file . The solution was to add a $(this).prop("value","") at the end of the function triggered by the change listener.